# help me to install and run version 2.9 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

How can I install Blender 2.9 in Ubuntu linux?

I installed the blender 2.9 file and extract it then when I tried open it there was so many files so I ran the file which is named 'blender'. I have tried to run the file multiple times, but have failed each time.

I also had a older version of blender 2.79 which I can use, but I need to use blender 2.9 for my animation project because it is the version my friends are using.

Comment: Most 2.9 files are compatible with 2.8x.

Comment: Just download the file from blender.org, uncompress the file, open the directory and run the file named **blender**.

Comment: Ubuntu has a snap store, download blender from there, make sure is the one made by the blender foundation. Just download and install like a regular app on a phone

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a file executable before running it.I will explain two ways to do that here.

### Gui way

- Right click on blender
- click on properties
- click on permissions tab
- check make as executable box
  [image]
- now apply your changes and run blender

### command line way

- navigate to the location were you have extracted blender via a file manager.
- right click on empty space and select open terminal here.Note open terminal option may be in different sub menu for you.

[image]

- now execute the following commands one by one

```
  chmod +x blender
  ./blender
```